# ( IF possible ) How to Vectorize This Training Process?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, vectorization, lstm

The problem is that I am only seeing a one second improvement during training when I switched from a CPU to a GPU. I believe this is because my training process is highly iterative instead of vectorized.

Any recommendations on vectorizing this Keras training?

```
e_num = 0
sample_count = len(trainX[0])
for e in range(epochs):
    e_num += 1
    print(e_num)
    for i in range(len(trainX)):
        model.fit(trainX[i], trainY[i], epochs=1, batch_size=32,
            verbose=2, shuffle=False,
            validation_split=fix_validation_split(0.05, sample_count,
            batch_size))
    model.reset_states()
```

The problem with Keras is that I'm having difficulty passing the fit function a 4-D dataset. Thus, I'm iteratively training over each 3-D dataset inside trainX. When I increased the batch_size from 1 to 32, training is much faster obviously. However, there is still only a 1 second time difference per epoch between the CPU and GPU. Is this because my training process is not properly vectorized? If so, what recommendations would you have whilst using Keras?

Thank you!

Comment: This is extremely weird training pipeline. Could you provide us with details about model and data?

Comment: I dont believe you can

Comment: @MarcinMożejko It is due to the fact that LSTMs in Keras do not appear to play well with 4-D data. Here is my data: [data](https://preview.ibb.co/dwXRUv/IMG_4571.jpg)

I'm training an LSTM on 3 dimensional time series data (numPatients, numFeatures, numTimesteps). The 4th dimension comes when I create the 3:1 (x,y) lag. So there's a fourth dimension in trainX that is a collection of (numPatients, numFeatures, 3 timesteps).

The LSTM iterates over trainX and trains on each (x,y) mapping inside each trainX[i]. The goal is that the LSTM learns to predict the next timestep given 3 prev. steps

Comment: @MarcinMożejko However, I am very much open to better recommendations!

Comment: But this lag is w.r.t. to timestep, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes. If you click the link in the last comment to a picture of the data that I've drawn it provides a nice visual.